# I get error: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: java, hibernate, javax

I get error: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.messagemanager.domain.User column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

There are my Entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity{

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }   

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User  extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{
    @Column(name = UserFieldsKey.ID, length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(updatable = false, insertable = false)
    @Transient
    private List<Message> listMessage = new ArrayList<>();

    public static class UserFieldsKey{
        public static final String NAME = "name";
    }

    public User() {
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    public List<Message> getListMessage() {
        return listMessage;
    }

    public void setListMessage(List<Message> listMessage) {
        this.listMessage = listMessage;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "Message")
public class Message extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{
    @Column(name = MessageFieldsKey.MESSAGE, length = 500, nullable = false)
    private String message;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "id_user")
    private Long id_user;

    public Long getId_user() {
        return id_user;
    }

    public void setId_user(Long id_user) {
        this.id_user = id_user;
    }

    public static class MessageFieldsKey{
        public static final String MESSAGE = "mes";
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String message, User user) {
        this.message = message;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

P.S. thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the value of UserFieldsKey.ID ?

Comment: @DmitriyS was the problem the one I tried answering?

Comment: Post has been closed.Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that's because you have this:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="user")
private User user;
```

which will map to `User.id`; and in `Message` you already have an `id` since you are extending `BaseEntity`

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved) I mistook in relationship between tables.